# Too many uses of “either”?

Tags: conjunctions, conjunction-reduction

The following is an excerpt from a software manual (where words in `monospace` type are commands):

> For *either* `predefined` or `user`, shows *either* predefined‐only or user‐defined‐only types that are  *either*  valid  in  (for predefined)  or  that were defined in (for user‐defined) the current language or later.

There are three uses of “either” in that sentence (italicized to highlight here, not in the original). Should all three be used? If not, which one(s) should be removed?  What's the general guideline for where and how many of “either” are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we format the example like this:

> For either [of the situations previously described]

> > (1) “predefined”

or

> > (2) “user”,

> > > shows either (i) predefined‐only

or

> > > (ii) user‐defined‐only types

> > > > that are either (a) valid in (for predefined) [the current language or later]

or

> > > > (b) that were defined in (for user‐defined) the current language or later.

You will see that there are not too many uses of either. You should omit none. The general guideline is that you use "either" as many times as is necessary to make your meaning clear.